# Order an if statement to ignore following tests if first test is null

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to say if this property is (Null OR Equals "" OR contains "ImageNotAvailable") Then go ahead and do something.  But when I try to use the code below, I get an object reference error.  I was hoping by putting `(Publisher.ThumbnailURL == null)` at the beginning of the test, the other tests would be ignored, but I get error above.

```
if ((Publisher.ThumbnailURL == null) | (Publisher.ThumbnailURL == "") | (Publisher.ThumbnailURL.Contains("ImageNotAvailable")))
```

I can simply split these up into "If Else's" but is there a way to specify that if the first test is null, don't try and figure out the rest of the If statement which will cause it to error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of [`|`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
if ((Publisher.ThumbnailURL == null) || (Publisher.ThumbnailURL == "") || (Publisher.ThumbnailURL.Contains("ImageNotAvailable")))
```

|| Operator

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands, but **only evaluates its second operand if necessary**.

Note that you could also use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as commented by Raphaël Althaus:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Publisher.ThumbnailURL) || Publisher.ThumbnailURL.Contains("ImageNotAvailable"))
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` would be nice for first 2 tests by the way.

Comment: Thanks very much guys - I suspected it'd be a simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, use `||` to evaluate the expression as early as possible, also, using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` would make the statement more brief:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Publisher.ThumbnailURL) || (Publisher.ThumbnailURL.Contains("ImageNotAvailable")))
```